# Using a macro to replace "create()" functions in a factory pattern style API

Tags: c++, api-design

I'm writing a C++ library with all classes making use of the *factory pattern*, i.e. having a private empty constructor and a private `void init()` function, which does the actual initialization of an instance. The classes that can be instantiated by the library user have a public static `create()` function which does the following:

```
static Class* create(int arg1, int arg2) {
    Class* ret = new Class();
    ret->init(arg1, arg2);
    return ret;
}
```

There are also several classes which *shall not be instantiated from outside the library*, so they don't provide a public `create()`.

These "internal classes" do have some `friend` relationships between each other, so they can instantiate each other. Let's assume I want to write as little code as possible, so I would like to avoid declaring and defining private `create()` functions for all the internal classes, but I would also like to avoid writing

```
InternalClass* foo = new InternalClass(); 
foo->init();
```

all the time an internal class gets instantiated. Instead it would be nice to have a single (template) function or macro that can create *any* internal class with just one line of code, e.g.

```
template<class T, typename ...Args> inline T* create(Args... args) {
    T* ret = new T();
    ret->init(args...);
    return ret;
}
```

The problem with the above function (which would be defined as a standalone function in a global shared header, thus the `inline` keyword) is that it bypasses the `friend` declarations between the classes and thus wouldn't compile.

The problem with a macro on the other hand is that it can't "return" a pointer to the instance as long as there is the statement `ret->init()` inside the macro, so using the macro like the following wouldn't be possible:

```
InternalClass* foo = CREATE(InternalClass, arg1, arg2);
```

Finally, my question is:

Is it somehow possible to create a macro that can be called in the above way (and without changing the return type of all the `init()` functions to a class type pointer, which would indeed allow the following: `#define CREATE(T, ...) (new T())->init(__VA_ARGS__)`)?

(Please note that this is more an *academic* than a *practical* question as I've already implemented the solution with the private `create()` functions, which works perfectly fine and seems to be the "cleanest" solution. I was just wondering if there *could have been* a solution with macros, too...)

Comment: What us up with init? Why not do it initialization in the constructor? Also, your factory method return type is actually the same as your class, so this factory is useless.

Comment: If you *really* want to use macros (you almost certainly don't), you'd probably need something like GCC's [statement expressions](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html): `#define CREATE(T, ...) ({ auto* ret = new T; ret->init(__VA_ARGS__); ret; })`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can mix both template and macro:

```
template <typename T, typename InitF, typename... Args>
T* CreateImpl(T* t, InitF init, Args&&...args)
{
    (t->*init)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    return t;
}
```

and the MACRO (to forward private stuff)

```
// I assume no overloads of T::init
#define CREATE(T, ...) CreateImpl(new T(), &T::init, __VA_ARGS__)
```